# Ubuntu Desktop Won't Go Full Screen Under VM

Tags: vmware, fullscreen

I've read other similar posts and nothing suggested has worked for me. Ever since I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware Workstation 12, whenever I entered full screen mode on VM, Ubuntu desktop went full screen too. But yesterday, after removing open-vm-tools and rebooting Ubuntu, the desktop booted up in a small window and I've been unable to expand the window at all. I've reinstalled open-vm-tools. I've rebooted VM and Ubuntu several times. As of now I can find no way to get the desktop to expand and I can't work with it as it is.

Comment: plz if the hint works, put it as the resolved

Answer (score 2):

when removing "open-vm-tools", you kind of removed the screen drivers of your VM, so it's beeing on minimmum resolution config, and when reinstall'em it stills on the minimum config, you've just to change the resolution config manually to have the full-screen resolution again.
;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove/uninstall open-vm-tools and run this command in your Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```

Now install open-vm-tools and reboot..it should fix your problem

## Update:

I have finally found the solution. The problem is only there when the VM tools are updated (at least by me) you need to "trigger" the screen after updating VBoxLinuxAdditions or VmWare tools...this command should solve the problem:

```
xrandr --auto
```

you might get this message if you don't have it installed:

```
The program 'xrandr' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

Then install it with the command and you should get fullscreen resolution again. Mine was triggered right away after i installed x11-xserver-utils.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and still no joy. Ubuntu desktop remains minimized no matter what I do with VM full screen.

Comment: Amending my comment of just 5 minutes ago. I dumped the package info for open-vm-tools (after reinstalling) and noticed that it "suggested" open-vm-tools-desktop. So I installed that package, rebooted, and guess what??? I'm back in business with a full screen Ubuntu desktop! Thanks for the assist.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help! That was exactls what i wrote....you needed to install it again after that command in my answer.....p.s. don't forget to click on the check to accept my answer :)

Comment: I have the exact same issue and this solution doesn't fix it.  :(

Comment: @Dustin Wyatt - answer updated try it out

Answer (score 0):

I've simply ran the real installer of vmtools (not the open verion..),and everything is good! full screen back and forth...
do a override every time you've been ask to with [no]..
Ami